# Telerik radgrid doesn't remember page number

Tags: .net, telerik, paging

I have a telerik radgrid-control on my page for showing a list of articles. If I click a page, then an article and then back to the list again I am back at the first page instead of the one I was at before.

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm assuming you're doing a postback and things are server side...

This is a 2 step process...

First in the OnClick event for clicking on an article, put the page index into a session variable.

Second, in the RadGrid's PreRender event get the page index from that previously set session variable.

```
// Set the page index, call this on your OnClick event
private void SetRadGridPageIndex(int PageIndex)
{
    Session["RadGridCurrentPageIndex"] = PageIndex;
}

// Get the page index, call this on RadGrid's PreRender event
// Don't forget to Rebind the RadGrid
private void GetRadGridPageIndex()
{
    // Go to the previously selected page
    if (Session["RadGridCurrentPageIndex"] != null)
    {
        this.RadGrid1.CurrentPageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(Session["RadGridCurrentPageIndex"]);
        this.RadGrid1.MasterTableView.Rebind();
    }
}
```

Comment: The answer is very very good, it really does what needed, just a little addition for completeness, when executing the PageRender, after the if in case of true, add something like this:  Session["RadGridCurrentPageIndex"] = null; or you will be in that PageIndex while value set in session, assuming you jumped to the PageIndex, then you don't need that value anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the Back button of the browser when you navigate back to the page with the grid? If so, you will need to use Cache or Session storage (for example) for the grid page index (CurrentPageIndex) and then restore it back.

Also make sure you use binding with NeedDataSource event or data source control.

Dick