# What is the difference between RadGrid.Rebind() and RadGrid.MasterTableView.Rebind()?

Tags: asp.net, telerik, webforms, radgrid

Using RadGrid for Asp.Net Ajax (from Telerik) I need to re-set the CurrentPageIndex. [Some examples](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/radgrid-and-paging-reset.aspx) say the next line of code should be **myGrid.Rebind()** while [others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086809/telerik-radgrid-doesnt-remember-page-number) suggest calling **myGrid.MasterTableView.Rebind()**. What's the difference? Which should I use?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`myGrid.MasterTableView.Rebind()` would rebind the top-level table on the RadGrid.

`myGrid.Rebind()` would rebind all tables on the RadGrid.

I recommend you to take a look to [this](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-mastertableview-difference.html) article in order to understand the difference between RadGrid and MasterTableView.