# Have to bind data to User Control using Telerik RadGrid inside another user control?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, telerik, plinqo

Basically I have created a user control containing a Telerik RadGrid, inside the control I have another two controls that have Telerik RadGrid inside them. I am trying to bind the modified data back into the User Control inside the parent user control. I have checked that the data is correct after they have been edited but when the form is binded again the inner controls have the same data as the form is first loaded. I am using RadWindow. Coworkers have suggested that it works with asp.net form controls however it seems that there is an issue with Telerik controls. Is there a easy way to force a rebind of the control?

Answer (score 0):

There is a [Rebind() method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044612/what-is-the-difference-between-radgrid-rebind-and-radgrid-mastertableview-rebi) you can call to enforce this.  This method causes the refresh and reloads the data and calls NeedDataSource.

Comment: Hi, I used the rebind method for the radgrid in the control inside my top control's radgrid but it did not call needdatasource.

Comment: Are you using DataSourceID approach to binding?  If so, it may not.

Comment: I am using DataSource='<%#Eval("Content")%>'

Comment: All then you should need to do is call DataBind() on the grid then, after page init.

Comment: There isn't a page init for the control, would this be control init then or would this be the page init of the page it self?